# JAVA / How to convert 2-byte float to double value

Tags: java

I am trying to convert 2 byte float value which is `0D 82` to double value on my project.

When I simulated that value I get the `28.2`.
So how can I convert that 2 byte float value to double value on java ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Floats are 4 bytes, not 2. Doubles are 8 bytes. What is this mysterious 2-byte float?

Comment: 28.2 in traditional IEEE float standard is 0x41e1999a. What standard generates that 2 bytes? What source system/architecture is this "float" coming from?

Comment: I try to convert that 2 bytes float value which is coming from KNX bus lane to double value.KNX is sending 2 bytes float when works with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following library:

https://sourceforge.net/p/calimero/wiki/Home/

It provides a Java API to the KNX network and its data types. This will most likely do what you want - specfically the `tuwien.auto.calimero.dptxlator.DPTXlator2ByteFloat` class.

You can use this code:

```
byte[] test = new byte[2];
test[0] = (byte)0x0D;
test[1] = (byte)0x82;

DPTXlator2ByteFloat floatTranslator = new DPTXlator2ByteFloat(DPTXlator2ByteFloat.DPT_AIR_PRESSURE);
floatTranslator.setData(test);
double value = (double)floatTranslator.getValueFloat();
```

the `value` variable will have the 28.2 value as expected.

Import the following in your maven dependencies to include the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.calimero</groupId>
    <artifactId>calimero-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta</version>
<dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: floatTranslator.setData(test); method requires one more parameter which is called offset.When I put the 0 as an offset it works.
Thanks for helps.

Comment: @rdvnbl Yes, there are two overloaded methods called `setData`. One with an offset, one without. Seeing as this is home automation you will probably be receiving a stream of data and you need to keep track of the offset. I merely chose the simplest implementation for clarity. Also, note the `DPTXlator2ByteFloat.DPT_XXX` argument to the constructor - this will be important and you will have to choose the correct one for the sensor byte stream.